# What paint to use to fill engraved letters on aluminium plate?

Tags: painting, paint, metal, aluminum

Basically I want to engrave letters and some symbols on aluminium box and fill them in using a paint, What paint should I use?

As far as I know aluminium usually gets painted by anodazing process. But still, I believe there must be a way to paint engraved stuff.

This is the box I want to engrave stuff on:
[image]

Example of the work:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For best results you need a etching type paint for aluminum or a Zink oxide primer then any paint. Aluminum oxidizes with air so it needs a primer or a paint designed for aluminum that actually etches so it bonds with the metal. Annodizing is used to protect the surface it is a plating type of solution in a bath so it is a bit different (and the surface is usually harder than aluminum.